# Find oldest java version that can compile a code

Tags: java, compilation

Is it even possible to write a test to check if a file compiles in particular version of Java?

Let's say I have jdk 1.8,1.7,1.6..... in my machine and need to find oldest java version that can compile the code.

The only way I can think of this is to make use of Runtime api. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you should really care about oldest version on java.

Comment: You should choose the version to build your project on and build all of it use that version.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `javac` version 1.8 with various `-source` options.

For example `javac -source 1.6 ...` should choke on any 1.7 or 1.8 specific language details (but it will not choke on using newer libraries).

To validate that a set of source code only uses the 1.6 API to go with a 1.6 source code style, you need to setup a maven build and use the "animal sniffer" plugin.  It will check that all the system library calls match a fingerprint taken from a stock 1.6 JVM (if you configure it as such).

There are other techniques, and you've already hinted at just downloading a JDK for each relase, which works, but is a bit of a mess eventually finding all the required JDKs.

Comment: Exactly the solution i was looking for. Thanks for pointing out "Animal Sniffer" plugin.